# Label is not showing text when the program is run

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a series of tests which when completed by a user the score is stored in a variable and written into a file. Within my program is a progress screen for each user, which is supposed to show all of the test scores in labels.

I have used this code to show the score in the label : `lblTopic1Score.Text = Topic1Score`

However when I run the system and go onto the progress form the label is blank. Can anyone help ?

Code for the Progress form:

```
Private Sub StProgress_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblTopic1Score.Text = Topic1Score
    lblTotalScore.Text = TotalScore`

    lblStName.Text = namest
    LblStSurname.Text = surnamest

End Sub
```

Module was created to store Public variables `Public Topic1Score As String`

This is a code extract from the test itself

```
If answers(i) = questions(i, 4) And FileOpenStatusTS = False Then

    Topic1Score += 1
    TotalScore += 1

End If

If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
    FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Append)
    FileOpenStatus12A1 = True

    'Once all the details have been entered and checked, then they are written to the Teacher accounts text file'
    WriteLine(1, Username, Topic1Score, TotalScore)
    FileClose(1)
End If
```

Comment: Ensure that your label's fore color is not the same as its back color. It's a long shot but still worth checking.

Comment: Also, why do you make additions to a `String` variable?

Comment: When you put a [breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.90).aspx) on that line of code and run it from Visual Studio, what is the value of Topic1Score when it hits that line of code?  And when you move to the next step, does the debugger show the text of the label properly, and it clears later?  Setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code while debugging is your best bet for finding your answer.

Comment: Thanks I have already checked this though.

Comment: I made it a String variable, because when It was an Integer it wouldnt write to the text file.

Comment: I'll do the breakpoints now thanks.

Comment: re: "I made it a String variable, because when It was an Integer it wouldnt write to the text file." it would have if you'd use the [.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Comment: You got it wrong, pal. Your variable should be an `Integer` and it should be casted as `String` when you need to write it somewhere. Don't make it a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly at the time your form loads `Topic1Score` is either null or empty.

Add `Debug.Assert(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Topic1Score))` on the first line of your `StProgress_Load` event handler:

```
Private Sub StProgress_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Assert(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Topic1Score))

    lblTopic1Score.Text = Topic1Score
    lblTotalScore.Text = TotalScore

    lblStName.Text = namest
    LblStSurname.Text = surnamest
End Sub
```

This will halt execution whenever the value is null or only contains blanks so you can make sure it never goes down below your radar when you are debugging.

Note that `Debug.Assert` does not get compiled in a release build so you do not have to worry about performance implications. Think of it as a simple tool that helps you debugging.

Also, this variable really shouldn't be of `String` type, but `Integer`. If you *do* need it as a string for some operation you can do `Topic1Score.ToString()`.

Comment: Sorry for being an Idiot but where exactly do you mean by the first line of the even handler, I can't find it.